# What is the difference between elgg_echo and echo

Tags: php, echo, elgg

I have just started on ELGG and am pretty confused on the functionality of the Elgg_echo, Elgg.echo and echo. Therefore, when is the most appropriate time to use Elgg_echo and echo

Hence, if I were want display the following option. Can I just use echo or do have to use elgg_echo to conform with the ELGG framework?

```
$dropdown = echo/elgg_echo'<DIV align="center", >
                    <select>
                        <option value="A">a</option>
                        <option value="B">b</option>
                        <option value="C">c</option>
                        <option value="D">d</option>
                    </select>
                </DIV>';
```

Please help to enlighten me. I am highly confuse between elgg_echo and echo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're talking about elgg_echo on PHP side. There's elgg.echo equivalent in JavaScript that additionally requires to be used after `init, system` event have fired.

**echo** is a PHP built-in language construct that sends the strings to the standard output.

**elgg_echo** on the other hand is the function that takes language tokens and transforms into appropriate translation according to current user's language settings. From the function description:

> Given a message key, returns an appropriately translated full-text string

You can read the details in the [internationalization](http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.12/guides/i18n.html) section of Elgg documentation.

Answer (score -1):

**echo** is `PHP` built-in language construct that sends the strings to the standard output.

where

**elgg_echo** is `elgg` function it returns an appropriately translated full-text string See the syntax for that below

```
elgg_echo($message_key, $args = array(), $language = "");

$message_key ->   The short message code
$args        ->   An array of arguments to pass through vsprintf().
$language    ->   Optionally, the standard language code
```